# How to create SoundCloud playlist using PHP wrapper

Tags: php, soundcloud

I am trying to create a playlist using the njasm PHP wrapper, which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/njasm/soundcloud). The reason I am using this wrapper is because it allows for direct user login. And for my purposes, this is a requirement.

Let me start by saying that I am able to connect to the API; before attempting to create a playlist, I do a few get requests for certain info.

Right now I am trying this

```
$response = $facade->post('/playlists', $prepaired_post_array)->request();
```

`$prepaired_post_array` contains

```
[0] = playlist[title]=LA Sun
[1] = &playlist[tracks][][id]=102981743
[2] = &playlist[tracks][][id]=93248225
[3] = &playlist[tracks][][id]=25780933
```

This statement returns code 422. Which, according to SoundClouds [API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#errors), is close to something right, but something is messed up. I have tried a few different things, but everything else just returns code 400, which is just a bad request.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SoundCloud API, but the [API example for `/playlists`](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#creating-sets) includes the "sharing" field - does adding this help? Also, do all the track IDs you specified actually exist?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Yes the id's do exist. I am pulling them from an existing playlist. What do you mean by sharing field?

Comment: Well, the sample looks like this: `client.post('/playlists', :playlist => {
  :title => 'My new album',
  :sharing => 'public',
  :tracks => tracks`,  but you didn't specify the "sharing" field

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I believe you're looking at the Ruby code on the documentation.

Comment: You're right that the examples between the languages are inconsistent, and it does make it look like the "sharing" field isn't mandatory, but it really doesn't matter which language I'm looking at. If a field is mandatory and you don't supply it, you'll get problems. Their server doesn't know (or care) what language you're using!

Comment: Maybe you should check your structure via a simple `echo json_encode($prepared_post_array)`. Do you get the same output as with this? `["title" => "LA Sun", "tracks" => [["id" => 102981743], ["id" => 93248225], ["id" => 25780933]]]`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using my library.

playlists at soundcloud are tricky. lately I've updated the library and tested what you need in the latest version.

**UPDATE 28-04-2015**: you'll need the latest 2.2.1 stable version or higher to use the below example code.

Note: version 3.x.x is still under heavy development, example below is for 2.x.x

<strike>Note: take in considerations that the Request object was changed in the way the requests are made to soundcloud further tests are needed before i recommend to use that version in production. (also that's why I still didn't tag it as stable version)</strike>

With this in mind, do this:

1) Download the latest <strike>MASTER</strike> 2.2.1 tag, or higher (If you installed it via composer update you composer.json to <strike>`"njasm/soundcloud": "dev-master"`</strike> `"njasm/soundcloud": "2.2.1"` and run composer update <strike>in a development environment.)</strike> You'll need any version above 2.2.0 stable but not 3.0.x since it's not stable yet.

after that try this code:

```
// initialize Soundcloud
// auth via User Credential Flow
$soundcloud = new \Njasm\Soundcloud\SoundcloudFacade(
    $clientID, $clientSecret
);

$soundcloud->userCredentials("user@email.com", "user_password");

// build playlist main array
$playlistData = array(
    "playlist" => array(
        "title" => "My2 great Title Playlist!",
        "sharing" => "public", // or private
    )
);

//create playlist at soundcloud and grab the response
$response = $soundcloud->post('/playlists', $playlistData)->request();

// build tracks array
$tracks = array(
    "playlist" => array(
        "tracks" => array(
            array("id" => 29720509), // Connect the Dots
            array("id" => 26057359) // Forgotten Values
         )
    )
);

// put tracks into playlist
$response = $soundcloud->put(
    '/playlists/' . $response->bodyObject()->id, 
    $tracks
)->request();

var_dump($response->bodyArray());
die();
```

This <strike>Should</strike> will work. 
Take in consideration also that every time you "PUT" a request to a playlist you have to build the tracks array with all the track IDS that you want in that playlist/set, soundcloud will erase all tracks and insert the new ones.

I Would like to ask you, if you find any issues with the library to report them in the github issues page.

Thanks and have fun!