# Updating Soundcloud Playlist via Soundcloud Wrapper

Tags: php, soundcloud

In reference to this post [How to create SoundCloud playlist using PHP wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156861/how-to-create-soundcloud-playlist-using-php-wrapper)

I am using the Njasm/Soundcloud Wrapper in PHP to manage our track uploads and playlist creation. According the the post referenced above I need to rebuild the entire track list whenever I want to update the playlist.

Is there a way to update a current playlist so that we can simply add a track to a playlist? Or do we have to rebuild the list of track id's each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for using my library.

In response to your question, and to the best of my knowledge, that's a limitation of the Soundcloud API itself. You'll have to recreate the playlists every time you want to update it.

Reference: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#creating-sets

Hope it helps.

PS - If you find a way to add/remove single track to/from an existing playlist, please be my guest and share the trick or send pull request in github. I'll be more then glad to merge it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a super sexy solution, but I just rebuild the list like this.

```
$currentPlaylist = 12312312312; // Id of target playlist
$response = $facade->get(
'/playlists/'.$currentPlaylist)->request();

$set = $response->bodyArray();
$trackList = array();
$trackNew = array();
foreach ($set['tracks'] as $episode) {

    $trackNew = array("id" => $episode["id"]);
    $trackList[] = $trackNew;
}

$tracks = array(
    "playlist" => array(
        "tracks" => $trackList)
    );

$response = $facade->put(
    '/playlists/' . $response->bodyObject()->id, 
    $tracks
)->request();
```